# How can i pull datas from document library?

Tags: web-part, list-view, web-services, soap

I got a document library.There are many documents. I want to group this documents programmatically. I want to pull datas and group them with codes later show with any web part. so , how can i pull documents' information? I can use javascript , SOAP web services , Web part. But i want basic steps.

Comment: Please provide needed information like , you're trying to get the document details through Server Side Code (Visual Web Part) or CSOM code or through Javascript .

Comment: I want to use Javascript or Web Part.